# How to configure ActiveMQ with LevelDB JNI driver?

Tags: performance, activemq-classic, leveldb

I am having trouble forcing ActiveMQ 5.10.1 on CentOS 6 (64bit) with Oracle JDK 8 to use JNI driver for LevelDB. When I set indexFactory="org.fusesource.leveldbjni.JniDBFactory" - my broker fails to start. When I omit it, it does start, but it uses Pure Java driver.

```
<persistenceAdapter>
    <levelDB directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb" indexFactory="org.fusesource.leveldbjni.JniDBFactory"/>
</persistenceAdapter>
```

I did install LevelDB rpm on my OS, but after the AMQ start, its log file indicates that it uses the pure java driver:

```
2015-01-27 05:44:48,172 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: LevelDB[/home/roman/amq/DISK1/broker1/data/leveldb] | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2015-01-27 05:44:48,233 | INFO  | Using the pure java LevelDB implementation. | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.LevelDBClient | main
2
```

I try adding the level-db jni jar file to the classpath, but AMQ fails to find the classes. Here is running broker (note classpath with the leveldbjni-1.8.jar - AMQ docs does not really explain if those optional libs are loaded or not by default?, so I added it by hand):

```
/home/roman/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/roman/amq/DISK1/broker1/conf/login.config -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/roman/amq/DISK1/broker1/tmp -Dactivemq.classpath=;/home/roman/amq/DISK1/broker1/conf;/home/roman/apache-activemq-5.10.1/lib/optional/leveldbjni-1.8.jar -Dactivemq.home=/home/roman/apache-activemq-5.10.1 -Dactivemq.base=/home/roman/amq/DISK1/broker1 -Dactivemq.conf=/home/roman/amq/DISK1/broker1/conf -Dactivemq.data=/home/roman/amq/DISK1/broker1/data -jar /home/roman/apache-activemq-5.10.1/bin/activemq.jar start
```

Here is the error I get in the log file when forcing JNI to be used for LevelDB:

```
2015-01-28 05:07:34,904 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@6276ae34: startup date [Wed Jan 28 05:07:34 PST 2015]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,139 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: LevelDB[/home/roman/amq/DISK1/broker1/data/leveldb] | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,193 | ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([broker1, null], java.lang.Exception: Could not load any of the index factory classes: org.fusesource.leveldbjni.JniDBFactory) | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,198 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.1 (broker1, null) is shutting down | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,201 | INFO  | Connector openwire stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,205 | INFO  | Connector amqp stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,208 | INFO  | Connector stomp stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,212 | INFO  | Connector mqtt stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,215 | INFO  | Connector ws stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,229 | INFO  | Stopped LevelDB[/home/roman/amq/DISK1/broker1/data/leveldb] | org.apache.activemq.leveldb.LevelDBStore | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,240 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.1 (broker1, null) uptime 0.135 seconds | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,243 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.1 (broker1, null) is shutdown | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,246 | INFO  | Closing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@6276ae34: startup date [Wed Jan 28 05:07:34 PST 2015]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
2015-01-28 05:07:36,252 | WARN  | Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@6276ae34: startup date [Wed Jan 28 05:07:34 PST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook.run(SpringContextHook.java:30)[activemq-spring-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:809)[activemq-broker-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.stop(XBeanBrokerService.java:122)[activemq-spring-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:601)[activemq-broker-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:73)[activemq-spring-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_31]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)[:1.8.0_31]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1638)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)[spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)[xbean-spring-3.16.jar:3.16]
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)[xbean-spring-3.16.jar:3.16]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)[activemq-spring-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)[activemq-broker-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)[activemq-broker-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)[activemq-console-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)[activemq-console-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:150)[activemq-console-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)[activemq-console-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)[activemq-console-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_31]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_31]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)[:1.8.0_31]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.10.1]
```

**The AMQ doc does not explain on how to configure LevelDB for JNI to work. Any suggestions?**

The reason I want to use JNI driver is because with pure Java driver my AMQ broker performs about ~20% slower than KahaDB in 80 concurrent user / 20 queues test. I am hoping JNI with LevelDB can make AMQ go faster than KahaDB configuration.

Comment: "Fails to start" is a bit vauge. You did not happen to peek at a log file or two?

Comment: added error info from the log file (did not do it the first time because the error is "simple" - it can't find the JNI classes or something else that is needed for JNI)

Comment: Does anybody use ActiveMQ with LevelDB? If yes, is that via JNI or pure Java implementation that ships with AMQ?

Comment: is there anybody from ActiveMQ community on this forum or shall I be using Apache forum for that? Or perhaps nobody uses AMQ with LevelDB?

Comment: Check out the official community forums instead - the user mail list and the IRC channel. It may address more people with LevelDB/AMQ knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I couldn't find the answer really documented anywhere else.  All I needed to do was download the appropriate JNI library to the ActiveMQ lib directory.  For example:

```
wget -O /etc/activemq/apache-activemq-5.13.0/lib/optional/leveldbjni-linux64-1.8.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/fusesource/leveldbjni/leveldbjni-linux64/1.8/leveldbjni-linux64-1.8.jar
```

Comment: thank you for the tip. I will test it when I get time and mark this as answered if it works. Thanks again!!